# How to indent text in a label? Swift, UIKit

Tags: swift, uikit, label

I have a text in a label right aligned. The label is in a dynamic table cell. But the text is very close to the right edge of the label and does not look presentable. It looks something like this:

1234.5|

Update: How it looks on the screen. 0 is adjacent to the right side of the screen
[image]

I would like to move the text a little bit from the right edge to make it look like this:

1234.5--|

In the text field, I use a custom class for this and override the following functions:

```
private let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 20)

override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    bounds.inset(by: padding)
}

override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    bounds.inset(by: padding)
}
```

The label has an UIEdgeInsets object too. But I could not find functions similar to the functions of techRect and EditingRect on the label.

It seems to me that the label should have such functions. Maybe they are called differently. But I have not yet been able to find them in the documentation and Google search has not helped either.

Maybe someone has already solved such a problem and could suggest either the solution itself or in which direction to look. Any ideas are welcome. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: So you just want the label to be wider? Adjust its `frame` then. Labels are not as complicated as text fields.

Comment: And I'm surprised you can see the edge of a label. Does the label have a non-clear background color? A screenshot of what is happening would be very helpful.

Comment: @Sweeper I have added a screen into the question above

Comment: Ah okay, so the label needs to be a little bit to the left, or a bit less wide. How have you set up the constraints? Depending on the constraints, this should be as simple as adjusting one of the constants.

Comment: i use 2 stacks: bottom, horizontal, in which label - texField - label. The second stack is vertical, with the bottom horizontal stack and one label. The second main stack is inserted into the cell of the table and all constraints are set to 0. I can change the right constraint for the main stack, but there is a red constraint error that I can't remove. So I thought there should be a simple adjustment within the label itself to reduce the width of the text area a bit from the label's right edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use a simple `UILabel` subclass with edge insets, like this:

```
class PaddedLabel: UILabel {
    var padding: UIEdgeInsets = .zero
    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawText(in: rect.inset(by: padding))
    }
    override var intrinsicContentSize : CGSize {
        let sz = super.intrinsicContentSize
        return CGSize(width: sz.width + padding.left + padding.right, height: sz.height + padding.top + padding.bottom)
    }
}
```

Then set your custom "padding" like this:

```
label.padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 20.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 20.0)
```

Quick example:

```
class PaddedTestVC: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let defaultLabel = UILabel()
        let paddedLabel = PaddedLabel()
        
        [defaultLabel, paddedLabel].forEach { v in
            v.backgroundColor = .green
            v.text = "Test Text"
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            defaultLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            defaultLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            
            paddedLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: defaultLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            paddedLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        paddedLabel.padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 12.0, left: 20.0, bottom: 12.0, right: 20.0)
    }
    
}
```

The top label is a default `UILabel` the bottom label is a `PaddedLabel` - the only difference is the `.padding`:

[image]

A better option (in my view) would be to constrain your stack view to the **margins** of the cell's contentView - that way you get the defined margins (top/bottom and sides) spacing for the device and traits.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a complete solution! And you are right that if the project uses a storyboard, then the easiest way is to set the stack constraints to margins. Thanks again!